# Type mismatch Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I do not understand how to fix and why the following error occurs:

> Type mismatch. Required: TestList Found: String

In a separate class, the **TestList** data class with one parameter **name** of the string array

```
data class TestList (val name: ArrayList<String>)
```

Next, in MainActivity, I create a variable to which I assign this same TestList

```
val recList = ArrayList<TestList>()
```

Next, I need to fill this array with string data:

```
for((key) in data.legends.all){
     recList.add(key)
}
```

Well, here I am getting this error, why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: What is the type of key object that you are retrieving from data.legends.all ?

Comment: its `String` as made clear by the error

Comment: I forgot to witness that . Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rectList` can only contain elements of type `TestList`, but you are trying to add a `String` to it, which it can't contain. hence you get the error.

You have to add a `TestList` object to the list, also there is no need to use a loop, since you already have an `Iterable<String>`

```
recList.add(TestList(ArrayList(data.legends.all)))
```

Comment: the loop is used to iterate over the Map and get the key from it.

Comment: `data.legends.all` is an `Iterable<String>` which contains all your keys, you can directly create an `ArrayList` from it without iterating

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Everything works. Sorted it out with your help